# How to update the controls present in two different update panels using the click event of two different buttons

Tags: asp.net

I am quite new to learning asp.net, so the question that I am asking may sound quite basic but I still need an answer as I am doing r&d with some of the toipcs.

I have 2 update panels in my page. Each contains a label. There are two buttons on my page, on the click event of the first button the label in the first update panel should get updated. On the click of the second button the label in the second update panel should get updated.
However when I click any of the two buttons both the labels get updated.

In the load event of the page the foll code is written

```
        Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

The code for  both the update panel is as follows:

```
              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
              </ContentTemplate>
              <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID= "Button1" EventName="click" />

              </Triggers>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>


              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
              </ContentTemplate>
              <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="click" />
              </Triggers>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I don't see a definition for Button1 or Button2 here.  Are you expecting them to do something other than a full post-back when they are clicked?  (A default button will do a full post-back I believe)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code from the page_load method and place it in the event of each of the buttons. So for button1 you put the code that updates label1 and for button2 you put the code that updates the label2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the triggers unless you're doing cross panel events.  However, you do need to properly set up your script manager and update panels:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
    EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="Panel1_Load">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1"/>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="Panel2_Load">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2"/>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here you'd put your code in `Panel1_Load(){}` and `Panel2_Load(){}`.

Notice the settings: `EnablePartialRendering="true"`
and: `UpdateMode="Conditional"`

If you don't want the `asp:Button` controls on your panels, you'd have to put them somewhere that would block their normal full post-back behavior.